# Relationship between two weak entities

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following ER model:

[image: ER model]

`User` can have multiple `Accounts` and every `Account` itself can have many `Transactions`. But in my model I have the relationship between two weak entities - `Account` and `Transaction`, and I cannot figure out how I should create my tables, specially `Transaction` table. What keys I should define and how I should relate them in the `Transaction` table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Account` is a weak entity, so its primary key is (`Id`, `UserId`) where `UserId` is the primary key for the `User` table. Same for the `Transaction`, that has to include in its primary key the fields (`Id`, `AccountId`, `UserId`). The ugly thing of this design is that, since most of the entities are weak, you need to drag the User Id everywhere, even if the transaction should logically depend on the Account only.

Comment: `you need to drag the User Id everywhere` this is what I am worried about the most. It does not seem right to me to have 3 primary keys (`Id`, `AccountId`, `UserId`) . I believe `UserId` should reference `User` table, but what about `AccountId`? Or maybe I should redesign the ER model?

Comment: if you can redesign it, why not? I would create weak entity only if necessary. Moreover, `Account` is already bound to the `User` through the foreign key, why would you want to include it in the primary key too?

Comment: It is because I want the `User` to have multiple `Accounts`, not only single one. And I want that every `User`'s `Account` to have a `Transaction`.

Comment: Yes, but each `Account` belongs to a single `User`, that is why you keep the User Id as a foreign key inside the Account entity. each account can have a global identifier, instead of binding it to Users. the only benefit (the only that jump to mind) you can have with weak entity in this case is when you need to query the accounts of a single user: if you declare cleverly the primary key you do not need to create an index on user ids.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you suggest me to make `Account` as strong entity where `Id` would be PK and `UserId` FK? The reason I want to make `Account` as weak entity is because I don't want user's accounts to be in the database if there is no such user.

Comment: for that you can enrich the foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Didn't think of that simple solution:)

Comment: You are welcome :)